# netty development http parsing issue

Tags: netty

I am trying to create a raw async http parser from netty's code ripping out all netty dependencies and I don't get this piece of code

```
private void skipControlCharacters(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    for (;;) {
        char c = (char) ByteBufferUtil.readUnsignedByte(buffer);
        if (!Character.isISOControl(c) &&
            !Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            buffer.position(buffer.position()-1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test that feeds in

```
 GET / HTT
```

and then feeds in

```
 P/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

Naturally the first packet with just the "GET / HTT" gets stuck in the loop until I get a BufferUnderflowException.  In async parsing, we may not always get the full packet of data(which is why http has the \r\n\r\n so we can tell when we have the complete http request packet).  or does this parsing only work if I do some preparsing??? such that I have to keep caching data myself until I receive the \r\n\r\n (I prefer no other layers but an http parser know about http parsing though and knowing \r\n\r\n would be http specific).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

never mind, dang stupid mistake, the G was not coming out correctly but came as space.

Comment: if you find any problems feel free to submit a bug-report to netty